# Javascript: La comprobacion 2 > 12 me devuelve true

Tags: javascript

en una parte de mi codigo tengo que comprobar si un numero intruducido por el usuarioes mayor que un maximo. Tengo esto escrito:

```
    console.log("mod: "+ mod);
    console.log("max_mod: "+ max_mod);
    console.log("mod > max_mod: "+ (mod > max_mod));
```

Cuando escribo 2 o un numero entre 2 y 9 el resultado de los console.log es el siguiente:

- mod: 2
- max_mod: 12
- mod > max_mod: true

Sin embargo, si escribo 1, 10 o 11 el resultado es este, que es el normal:

- mod: 1
- max_mod: 12
- mod > max_mod: false

No se porque pasa esto, los numeros los recojo de distintas variables asi:

```
var mod = $(this).parents(".modal-content").find("#input_num_mod").val();
var max_mod = $(this).parents(".modal-content").attr('data_mod');
```

¿Alguien sabe porque puede estar pasando esto?

Comment: Utilizando tu código no me ocurre ese problema. Puedes probar añadiendo     console.log("mod "+ mod + " > max_mod "+ max_mod+": "+ (mod > max_mod)); para verificar el valor de las variables en el momento de compararlas y ver si por algún motivo el valor se está cambiando.

Comment: He puesto eso tambien y los valores no cambian. He comprobado que los numeros me los guarda como strings, pero eso no deberia ser ningun problema tampoco no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema es que la comparación se está haciando a nivel de Strings no de numeros

Prueba a parsear a entero los valores con parseInt

```
var mod = parseInt($(this).parents(".modal-content").find("#input_num_mod").val());
var max_mod = parseInt($(this).parents(".modal-content").attr('data_mod'));
```

Ojo, deberas comprobar que son numeros también.

Comment: En principio con eso me funciona ya. Habia usado el parseInt sobre las variables antes pero seguia sin funcionar. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: tambien puedes probar con `(Number(mod) > Number(max_mod))`